# Table of Contents - overlapping text

Tags: table-of-contents

I am trying to format the table of contents of my MA thesis. For some reason, if I have no sections within a chapter, the chapter titles in the ToC are overlapping. Any ideas why?

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc,fmtcount}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.\ }
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\fontfamily{ptm}\large\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{5pt}{\large}
\titlecontents*{chapter}
[0pt]
{\addvspace{1em}}
{\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\, -- \,}
{\bfseries}
{\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\section{AAA}
\chapter{Theory}
\chapter{Something else}

\end{document}
```

[image: pdf]

Comment: Welcome, comment out the `titlecontents` block and see what happens. You forgot to place any vertical space.  Try  `{\bfseries\hfill\contentspage\\*[\baselineskip]}`

Comment: Use `\titlecontents` instead `\titlecontents*`, i.e. remove the star.

Comment: Removing the star works wonders. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the unstarred version of `\titlecontents`

```
\titlecontents{chapter}
[0pt]
{\addvspace{1em}}
{\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\, -- \,}
{\bfseries}
{\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}
```

to get

[image]