# Table of Contents Overlap - tocloft attempted

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

The sub-section numbers in the ToC are overlapping the title.

I've attempted the solution on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308518/table-of-contents-overlapping-text), but it doesn't work for me.

Below you will find a sample document to recreate the issue.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,headheight=48pt,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table,usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{arev}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{paralist}

% define custom colors
\definecolor{primary}{HTML}{8bc34a}
\colorlet{primarylight}{primary!60!white}
\colorlet{primarylightest}{primary!10!white}
\definecolor{secondary}{HTML}{000000}
\colorlet{secondarylight}{secondary!60!white}
\colorlet{secondarylightest}{secondary!80!white}
\definecolor{tertiary}{HTML}{1a237e}
\colorlet{tertiarylight}{tertiary!60!white}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{FFFFFF}

% define document formatting
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{}
\rfoot{PROPRIETARY \& CONFIDENTIAL}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\lfoot{OTHER THING}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{primary}}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% document coloring
%\let\oldheadrule\headrule
%\renewcommand{\headrule}{\color{secondary}\oldheadrule}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\sectionfont{\color{primary}}
\subsectionfont{\color{secondary}}

% table of contents 
%\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{2em}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\arrayrulecolor{secondarylight}

\title{broken}
\author{}
\date{March 2022}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{toc}{}
\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}
\subsection{Sub-section}

\end{document}
```

[image: overlapping numbers on sub-section title]

Comment: See the `tocloft` package on how to configure the size of the box that contains the section number

Comment: Btw please always make your examples **minimal** you're loading several package that are not related to the toc, including the fancyhdr confoguration

Comment: Here's another question where an overlapping problem needed to be fixed: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415)

Answer (score 0):

Your question title includes "tocloft attempted" but there is no `usepackage{tocloft}` in your MWE. So, how did you use `tocloft`? Have you even read the manual which tells you what it can do for you?

Your MWE is far too long with irrevalent packages and code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
%\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{7em} % cater for very long subsection numbers, but better
\addtolength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{{2em} % increase space for subsection numbers by 2em
```